# Kerberos kdc is unable to bind to ldap

Tags: security, kerberos, mitkerberos

I am following this guide to setup Kerberos with LDAP. I have followed all the steps. But when I am running kadmin.local it exits with following error:

> Authenticating as principal root/admin@EXAMPLE.COM with password.
>
> kadmin.local: Cannot bind to LDAP server 'ldaps://' as 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com': Can't contact LDAP server while initializing kadmin.local interface

```
-- Subject: Unit krb5-kdc.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit krb5-kdc.service has begun starting up.
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Starting Kerberos 5 Key Distribution Center...
-- Subject: Unit krb5-kdc.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit krb5-kdc.service has begun starting up.
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 krb5kdc[17707]: Cannot bind to LDAP server 'ldaps://' as 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com': Can't contact LDAP server 
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 krb5kdc[17707]: krb5kdc: cannot initialize realm EXAMPLE.COM - see log file for details
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 sudo[17678]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Kerberos 5 Key Distribution Center.
-- Subject: Unit krb5-kdc.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit krb5-kdc.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 02 06:19:12 ubuntu-512mb-blr1-01 systemd[1]: krb5-kdc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: `server 'ldaps://'` does not look like a valid hostname for an LDAP server, I would expect to see something like: `server 'ldaps://ldap.example.com'` ; is your LDAP server defined correctly?

Comment: I have tried with hostname also, still no success @HBruijn

Comment: I'll ask the obvious: if you try to telnet to the LDAP port on the LDAP server, does it get through? You can try `nc -v ldap.example.com 389` (replace 389 with 636 if that is the port the LDAP server is using).